# Добавление текстового файл в проект с++

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Мне необходимо добавить текстовый файл в проект в Visual Studio 2010 (проект на С++), сейчас я работаю с файлом, одержимое файла я читаю построчно и записываю туда новое значение. Файл храниться на диске D и это неудобно: при перемещении проекта необходимо перетаскивать и файл.. Глупо... Добавить в проект текстовый файл при помощи меню я могу, но #include  выдает ошибку

```
  Cannot open include file: 'TextFile1.txt': No such file or directory
```

Что делать?

Comment: Вы хотите включить текст из файла в исходный код? Или при чём тут #include?

Comment: Такое ощущение, что вы не понимаете разницы между файлом проекта и файлом данных. Файлы проекта обычно статические - они изменяются только программистом в процессе работы над проектом (упрощенно, конечно). Файлы данных в проект не включаются. Зачем вам этот файл в проекте, какую роль он играет в разработке программы?

Comment: Добавьте этот файл в проект, и выберите в свойствах его как ресурс, + опцию перечитывать каждый раз. После каждой сборки этот файл будет копироваться в выходной каталог приложения, `bin/Debug` например. Делать `include` на этот файл не следует :) хотя вам виднее, что там внутри.

Comment: Если вы хотите чтоб файл обновлялся после работы собранной вами программы и в проекте, в свойствах проекта пропишите копирование этого файла обратно, в директорию проекта, в секции Pre/Post build action.